# How to replace an image with another on button click

Tags: image, onclick

Hi I have a problem that I can't quite solve. I'm a total noob with HTML/Javascript, so I'm not sure how to proceed. The instructions are in the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Q2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="342.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function swap() {

            if (Math.random()>.5){
                document.getElementById("c").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("f").src = "images/f.jpg";

            } else {
                document.getElementById("d").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("f").src = "images/f.jpg";
            }

        }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Add code so that clicking the button  changes either the src "c.jpg" or "d.jpg" to "f.jpg" The choice of which should be replaced
    should be determined randomly.</p>


<img src="images/c.jpg" id="c"><br>
<img src="images/d.jpg" id="d">
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="swap()">OK</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The original problem had everything but the scripts. When I try this, I'm able to get the image c or d to disappear, but image f doesn't appear. I don't know how to get the image to show. getELementById won't work because I haven't made an id, but how do I do that without having image f showing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Please try answering your question

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're missing html

Try add `f` html element for work:

`<img src="images/f.jpg" id="f">`

Comment: I've tried doing this, but then the image is there before click the ok button. I need to have just images c and d there beforehand. Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The p tag in the html is talking about c.jpg, d.jpg and **e.jpg**.
Its not talking about f.jpg, you may want to check that

with the assumption that it is e.jpg and not "f.jpb". And also assuming that you have e.jpg in your images folder. Below code will work fine (small modification in the script)

function swap() {

```
        if (Math.random()>.5){
            // document.getElementById("c").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("c").src = "images/e.jpg";
            

        } else {
            // document.getElementById("d").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("d").src = "images/e.jpg";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry typo it is indeed talking about f.jpg. There is no e.jpg. I still encounter the same problem where image f isn't showing up, and i can confirm that the f.jpg is in the same place as c and d

Comment: The code is working fine for me. Hope you noticed within getElementByID , I have put c and d (and not f).  you can replace e.jpg to f.jpg. Hope it helps